# Stackdriver GCE JVM monitoring setup problems

Tags: java, jvm, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I have a custom instance running on Windows Server 2016 where I need to monitor my Java processes.

I setup Stackdriver, installed the monitoring agent and followed this guide for JVM monitoring https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm

However no matter what I do I can not see any of my processes when setting up an Alerting policy within Stackdriver's console.

There are 2 steps in the guide I am unsure how to follow:

> 1. On your VM instance, download jvm-sun-hotspot.conf from the GitHub configuration repository and place it in the directory
>      /opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.d/

Where exactly do I place the .conf file?

> 2. Edit the downloaded configuration file and replace JMX_PORT by the port on which your JVM is configured to allow JMX connections.

How do I get the port?

Sorry if this seems obvious but I'm pretty new to this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This might help someone:
The StackDriver Monitoring Agent actually does see my Java processes after all, however only those that use 32bit Java..

Answer (score 1):

All the steps and instructions on the [JVM plugin page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm) have instructions relevant for linux, and windows is not even mentioned there. So it could be quite possible that the JVM plugin is supported only on linux.

Since your code is already running on a JVM, you might want to consider if it is possible to move your application from a Windows VM to a linux VM.

> [**Enabling the JVM monitoring plugin**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm#enabling_the_jvm_monitoring_plugin)
>
> Java Virtual Machines are monitored via JMX.
>
> On your VM instance, download jvm-sun-hotspot.conf from the GitHub
>   configuration repository and place it in the directory
>   `/opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.d/`:
>
> ```
> (cd /opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.d/ && curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-agent-service-configs/master/etc/collectd.d/jvm-sun-hotspot.conf)
> ```
>
> Edit the downloaded configuration file and replace JMX_PORT by the
>   port on which your JVM is configured to allow JMX connections.
>
> After adding the configuration file, restart the monitoring agent by
>   running the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo service stackdriver-agent restart
> ```
>
> Information on other plugin configuration options can be found at
>   collectd.org.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You are probably right. I have not found much information on setting up on Windows.
I'll try to setup on Linux soon...however I have never worked with Linux so I wanted to avoid it.